# Add turnover column to my pivot table using PowerPoint

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerpivot

I am using powerpivot to create some metrics. On one pivot table, I want to show hires, terms and actives and then turnover % for each month.

I have the Hires, Terms & Actives powerpivot data working, however I do not know how I can add the turnover calculation.

Is there a way to insert a new column to a pivot table and run a simple division calculation in it?

*tried posting image of my data, not sure why site will not post image for me

one line of of table would look like such

```
Division  | Hires | Actives | Terms | Turnover
Corporate | 5     |  150    | 3     | (terms/actives)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the following measures:

```
SumActives:=
SUM(<fact table>[Actives])

SumTerms:=
SUM(<fact table>[Terms])

Turnover:=
[SumActives] / [SumTerms]
```

[Adding a measure to a Power Pivot model.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg399077%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Upon researching I found [this thread on MrExcel](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/power-bi/625617-grand-total-average-sum-sales-per-month.html) that solved my question!

First create a measure

```
ValueSum:=SUM(Table1[Value])
```

then create a measures that takes the average of the monthly totals of the previous measure.

```
=AVERAGEX(VALUES(Table1[Month]),[ValueSum])
```